# Azure function with OrchtestrationTrigger does'nt work with local Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I develop an Azure Function App with some timer triggered functions.
For my local debug I set in the **local.settings.json**:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

Everything works fine locally using the Azure Storage Emulator.

But if I add a **orchestration triggered** function e.g.:

```
[FunctionName("Function2")]
public void Function2([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
   ...
}
```

the code compiles, start but none of the timer triggered function is called.

If I change the "**AzureWebJobsStorage**" to a real azure storage connection, everything works fine again.

Is there a way to use and test both timer triggered and orchestrated function pure local with the Azure Storage Emulator?

Comment: Do you see any warning on the console when you run the functions having OrchestrationTrigger method with UseDevelopmentStorage storage?

Comment: No, it just stops (doesn't show further information) after listing all functions and there correct start type (timertriggered, orchestrated).

Comment: What is your version of Azure Storage Emulator?

Comment: It's 5.10 - the latest downloadable version